# How do I install CocoaPods on iMac Ventura Version 13.6 ? I have tried installing it multiple times without success. (Flutter)

Tags: ios, flutter, macos, dart, macos-ventura

I have tried to install CocoaPods with both `pod install` and `sudo gem install cocoapods`, but it has not worked for me.[image: Error]

Comment: You will need to use homebrew to install ruby first

Comment: After installing Homebrew and Ruby, I tried to install CocoaPods, but it was not working. @Paulw11